# TeX4ht does not generate correct paragraphs when I use in-line footnotes and KOMA-script

Tags: footnotes, koma-script, tex4ht

I want to generate HTML from LaTeX by TeX4ht (from TeX Live 2022).
This is my MWE.tex:

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\begin{document}
    This is paragraph 1.\footnote{This is a footnote.}
    
    This is paragraph 2.
\end{document}
```

I want to obtain in-line footnotes and therefore I executed the following command:

```
$ make4ht MWE.tex "fn-in"
```

The result:

[image: There is only one paragraph.]

I got only one paragraph.

If I use the standard `book` document class instead of the KOMA-script `scrbook` class, I get the desired result of two paragraphs:

[image: There are two paragraphs.]

How can I get two paragraphs with the KOMA-script document class? Is this a bug in TeX4ht?

Comment: Because there are no problems without `fn-in` and also no problems using `lwarp` instead of `TeX4ht`, I think this is indeed a `TeX4ht` bug and should be reported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that paragraphs need to be handled in footnotes, and for some reason, the next paragraph is ignored when you use `scrbook`. I've fixed this issue in TeX4ht sources, you can fix it now with this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\append:def\c:footnotetext{\ShowPar}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It explicitly tells TeX4ht to show the next paragraph after footnote. With this change, everything seems OK:

[image]

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a lot!